# Can PC hardware affect internal audio capture?

Tags: audio, sound-card

Put another way, if I'm having some audio output static issues, and I record my internal desktop audio using something like OBS, virtual audio cable, or stereo mix, and the static is present in the file (eg I can send it to another device and still hear it), does that rule out hardware issues (like soundcard/speaker problems)? I think it would rule it out, since I assume that internal audio capture just captures the digital signal being fed to the soundcard/speakers, so the hardware wouldn't have a chance to affect the signal yet. But that's just a guess because I couldn't find much information online about how internal audio capture actually works.

Comment: You can also get crackling when the software playing the audio experiences buffer underruns. The recording software can also fail to record all data in time.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually Radio Frequency interference [RFI].
Note that many people will claim it's a "ground loop" but this is actually very unlikely. It's leakage, though it will never hurt to make sure a desktop is correctly grounded [earthed].

There's little you can do about it, as it's often down to the manufacturer cutting corners.
If you have any peripherals connected, try without them [right down to trying a wired mouse instead of wireless]. If a laptop, try on battery power rather than mains - the PSU can contribute with high frequency 'spill'; very common in modern switch-mode power supplies.

For a desktop you can sometimes mitigate this slightly using an external USB sound card - simply by moving the DAC away from the internals you get a bit of separation. If your entire routing is internal, this will only help if the noise is being picked up inside the DAC rather than before it. As your interference is in a file generated entirely inside the machine, I doubt it would help.
Trying to track down which components are responsible is likely to be an unfruitful search. Anything with high frequency switching could be responsible & should have been RF damped by the manufacturer.

Comment: but if it were a RFI / sound card issue, how would it affect the internal audio capture? I would expect internal audio capture to look at the digital signal at the OS level, before it's even send to the soundcard and peripherals

Comment: My guess is you're recording something that's already affected. tbh, this type of diagnosis is easier if you can hear a sample, & it's also one of those 'being there' things - checking whether picture affects sound, or such as mouse movement. Were you, for instance. to route an mp3 through a DAW then Export the file, I doubt the noise would be there, as the DAW to achieve that would go nowhere near the computer's audio path.

Comment: good point, yeah I'll have to experiment more. Thanks